# SSRS URL Coding

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, uri

Is there a way to encode a URL for an SSRS Report?

I tried the following, but the output does not match what I need:

Code:

```
System.Uri.EscapeUriString("Receiving Inspection/Receiving Inspection End Of Lot")
```

Result:

```
Receiving%20Inspection/Receiving%20Inspection%20End%20Of%20Lot
```

I also tried...

Code:

```
System.Uri.EscapeDataString("Receiving Inspection/Receiving Inspection End Of Lot")
```

Result:

```
Receiving%20Inspection%2FReceiving%20Inspection%20End%20Of%20Lot
```

SSRS wants the following format...

```
Receiving+Inspection%2FReceiving+Inspection+End+Of+Lot
```

Or should I just replace space's with "+" sign?

Thanks
jlimited

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post that may hekp.  http://www.jensbits.com/2012/01/23/generate-sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs-report-as-pdf-from-url-with-vb-net-or-c-net/